# How to make every new div draggable?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to ask for some help with the following please. Basically, I'm trying to make a new `<div>` every time I press a button. Then, I want to add a function that would make every new `<div>` able to be dragged and moved when I click on it and when I release the mouse it drops (every new `<div>` should move separately). I have tried many things, but all of them seem not to be working well. The result I get is that either only the first `<div>` is moving or all `<div>`s move together. I have not added my moving function because it is not well arranged (hard to understand because I tried many things). I'm also not allowed to use JQuery.

Could you please advice me on what to do? Thank you.

```
<html>
<body>
    <button id="mybutton">Create a new moveabl div</button>
    <script>
        var create = document.createElement("div");
        create.id = "dragm2";
        document.body.appendChild(create);
        var count = 0;
        var text = document.createTextNode("mu yu ");
        document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            count++;
            var create = document.createElement("div");
            create.id = "dragme" + count;
            create.style.background = "green";
            create.style.height = "170px";
            create.style.width= "70px";
            create.appendChild(text);
            document.body.appendChild(create);
        });

        document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            console.log(event.target.nodeName);
            console.log(event.target.id);
            var movenow = event.target.id;
            if (movenow !== null && event.target.nodeName !== "BUTTON" ) {
                document.getElementById(movenow).addEventListener('mousedown', hold, false);
                document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', release, false);
                function hold() {
                    document.getElementById(movenow).addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
                    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
                }
                // ==> On Realease Function <==
                function release() {
                    document.getElementById(movenow).removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
                    document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
                }
                function move(event) {
                    var epY = event.clientY;
                    var epX = event.clientX;

                    if (document.querySelectorAll("input[name='revertxy']:checked").length >= 1) {
                        epY = event.clientX;
                        epX = event.clientY;
                    }

                    event.target.style.position = 'absolute';
                    event.target.style.top = epY + 'px';
                    event.target.style.left = epX + 'px';
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to use the draggable attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable. How does the code you posted even make one div draggable?

Comment: Can you recreate what you've tried inside of a jsFiddle? The code you've shared doesn't help necessarily since we can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const div = document.createElement("div");

  div.className = 'draggable';

  div.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  document.body.appendChild(div);

});

function mouseUp() {
  this.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
  this.classList.remove('grabbing');
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  this.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
  this.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, true);
  this.classList.add('grabbing');
}

function move(e) {
  this.style.position = 'absolute';
  this.style.top = getMousePosition(e).client.y - (this.clientWidth / 2) + 'px';
  this.style.left = getMousePosition(e).client.x - (this.clientHeight / 2) + 'px';
}

function getMousePosition(evt) {

  var pageX = evt.pageX;
  var pageY = evt.pageY;
  if (pageX === undefined) {
    pageX = evt.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    pageY = evt.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }

  var rect = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var offsetX = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  var offsetY = evt.clientY - rect.top;

  return {
    client: {
      x: evt.clientX,
      y: evt.clientY
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Create a new moveabl div</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, you beat me to it - pretty similar answer. Note clientX and Y are not available in all browsers. Also will need to remove offsets etc to get a real mouse position in all situations.

Comment: @Matt_S Hi Matt_S thanks for the comment. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
    <style>
    body { position: relative}
    div {
        width:100px; height: 100px;
        background:#f00;
        position: absolute;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <button id = "ayoo">Create a new moveabl div</button>

<script>

 var count = 0
 var moving=false; 
 var mx,my;

document.getElementById('ayoo').addEventListener('click', function () {
        count++
        var mydiv = document.createElement("div")
        mydiv.id= "aya"+count
        document.body.appendChild(mydiv)

        mydiv.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            moving = true;
            this.style.backgroundColor="#00ff00";
        });
        mydiv.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            if(moving) {
                getmouse(e);
                this.style.top = my - 50;
                this.style.left = mx - 50;
            }

        });
        mydiv.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
            moving = false;
            this.style.backgroundColor="#ff0000";
        });
});

function getmouse(e){
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY)
    { 
      mx = e.pageX;
      my = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)
    { 
      mx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
      my = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    }  
}

</script>

</body>
```